# How to transform SRID 3035 to SRID 4326?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, srid

I have data in the ETRS 89 LAEA format (SRID: 3035). But I have problems to transform it.

Example data:
    N2736 E4541

I want to transform it to WGS84 (SRID: 4326), to check the coordinates on a map.

My transformation looks like this:
    SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(27.36 45.41)',3035),4326))

I get: POINT(-29.0867265338903 12.9940786314927)
But the point should be in Germany and not in the atlantic ocean :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At a guess, your point should be about 5.5km southeast of *Bad Reichenhall* right?

If so, the problem you have is you're interpreting your input coordinates incorrectly. The clue is in the source projection's name: *LAEA* which stands for *Lambert Azimuthal Equal-Area*, which is a projection that uses linear units (metres in this case) rather than angular units.

So your data of N2736 E4541 should be translated into metres - and here's the rub, they're in 1000's of metres, so your actual coordinate is 4541000, 2736000 (eastings are usually given before northings). If I use GDAL's [gdaltransform](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html):

```
$ gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:3035 -t_SRS EPSG:4326
```

and type in the coordinates:

```
4541000, 2736000
```

I get:

```
12.9300691689392 47.6983999922817
```

Which puts me near the border between Bavaria and Austria.

In terms of PostGIS, you'd use:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4541000 2736000)',3035),4326));
```

Which returns me:

```
                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(12.9300691689392 47.6983999922817)
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank's, that's it! I have just the information about the country, so I checked other points in different countries, and it worked everytime well!
One little mistake: As you said, east before north, so it's the wrong way around in the select statement ;)

Comment: `gdaltransform` interpreter doesn’t seem to work with the comma, you have to provide the two coordinates separated by a space.